# electron ipc with HTML5 element

Tags: node.js, ipc, electron

In a preload webview, I "hook" the click event, to get some informations about some buttons on my webpage.
Sounds like

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    ipcRenderer.send('click', e.srcElement);
});
```

On mainprocess, I received the event, but I cannot read HTML5 values of srcElement (value, nodeName, ...)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

srcElement is deprecated. Use Event.target instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement